# Non-blocking socket still continues to block on send()

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I have a program interacting with two servers (all on localhost), which essentially forwards data from one server to the other.
I am trying to create a scenario where the server sending the initial data will close its connection to the middle-program because the server receiving the data has a very slow connection to the middle-program. The buffers of the middle-program should get filled, and it shouldn't be able to receive any data from the server sending data. As a result of this inactivity, the server sending data should timeout and close the connection, resulting in an in-complete data transfer.
I am trying to do it in the following way:

**Program at server sending the data**

```
import socket

interval_sec = 3
TCP_KEEPALIVE = 0x10

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, 1)
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPALIVE, interval_sec)


sock.bind(('', 9000))


sock.listen(5)


while True:
    conn, addr = sock.accept()


    f = open('test.txt', 'r')
    file_data = f.read(1024)
    while (file_data):
       conn.send(file_data)
       file_data = f.read(1024)
    f.close()
    print "sent"
```

**Middle program forwarding the data**

```
import socket
import select
import time
import struct

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

recv_timeout = 2
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVTIMEO, struct.pack('LL', recv_timeout, 0))

total_data=[]
total_sent=0;
data=0;

sock.connect(('localhost', 9000))
sock2.connect(('localhost', 8001))

sock2.setblocking(0)
sock.setblocking(0)

j=0

while 1:
    read, write, errors = select.select([sock], [sock2], [], 2)
    if read:
        data=sock.recv(1024, socket.MSG_DONTWAIT)
        total_data.append(data)
        #time.sleep(10)
    if write:

        if data:
            try:
                data_sent=sock2.send(data, socket.MSG_DONTWAIT)
                total_sent+=data_sent
                data=data[data_sent:]
                print data_sent
            except socket.error, e:
                if e.errno != errno.EAGAIN:
                    raise e
    else:
        print "Not writable"
```

**Program at server receiving the data**

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

sock.bind(('', 8001))


sock.listen(5)


while True:
    conn, addr = sock.accept()

    with open('received_file', 'wb') as f:
        while True:
            file_data = conn.recv(100)
            print('receiving data...')
            if not file_data:
                break
            f.write(file_data)
    f.close()
    conn.close()
```

The problem I'm facing is that, the middle-program's sockets are blocking although they should be acting as non-blocking.

Are my programs fundamentally wrong, and I'm missing the whole point or do I need to make some minor tweaks?

Thanks :)

Comment: How do you know that the sockets are blocking?

Comment: You should note that `select` is bocking also on non blocking sockets.

Comment: @syntonym Because of the print statements in the middle-program and receiving server

Comment: why did you seperate socket sender and receiver ? I just wonder it :)

Comment: @AshishPatil Can you share the output that indicates that they are blocking? I don't see anything wrong with the socket code (besides that you use `setblocking(0)` **and** MSG_DONTWAIT but I don't think that it should produce your results (blocking sockets).

Comment: @AshishPatil Has it occured that it is possible data is None?

Comment: `9000 to 9000` ? Bind declare transmit and receive, so can't use same port with same thing. Client source port is free why using `9000` again ? Try another port on client side(source). Like this : Your pc got apache server so you can't use as source `80` port again.

Comment: Tips: Use `socket.create_connection`, meaning `which_port_available TO target_port`.

Comment: @syntonym you need to run the code to see that it is blocking. The print statements all print 1024 bytes

Comment: @Natecat the data is definitely not None

Comment: @RockOnGom Just a hypothetical scenario to understand phpfpm, nginx and HAProxy :)

Comment: And that is wrong? You `select` so you will only receive data if there is some. Do you expect that there is sometimes no data to send?

Comment: @syntonym No, the thing is I send 1024 bytes, while the receiver accepts only 100 bytes. So, shouldn't the send() call return 100 bytes?

Comment: I think the 1024 bytes are buffered in the outgoing buffer, and the receiving socket is receiving fast enough so that when you want to send 1024 bytes again there is enough space in the outgoing buffer. (There is also an receiving buffer so if they are large enough the discrepancy between the recv and send size will probably not matter)

Comment: @syntonym, hmm that makes sense. How do you suggest I go about to achieve the scenario?

Comment: I think the way you coded it now the connection will never be broken because you buffer all data in `total_data` and the connection between process 1 and 2 is fast enough. Either restrict the size of `total_data` *and* make the sending of dater slow enough so that the size restriction will get hit or make the read of process 2 slow enough so that the network buffer of process 1 will get filled. Although.. I'm not sure how TCP keep alive works, but I think it will be "intelligent" enough to still keep alive, so that may not work? What exactly is your usecase here?

Comment: @syntonym I am trying to reciprocate a scenario that one of friends faced in a server (users with slow download speed weren't able to completely download data). Is it possible that I can control the speed of transfer of data from middle-program to process 2?

Comment: @AshishPatil I think if you add some `sleep(2)` (or whatever) to the process 3 (Program at server receiving the data, which I think you call process 2) should slow the connection down. I'm still not sure if "TCP magic" will somehow deal with the problem somehow or how big the network buffers are.

Comment: @syntonym I tried that. Sending-server sends a keep-alive and the middle-program sends back a ZeroWindow message

Comment: @AshishPatil Isn't that what you wanted? The receiving programm (process 3) empties its buffer too slow, so the sending buffer in process 2 (middle program) jams and finally the jam hits the receiving buffer of middle-program which then tells the sending programm (process 1) that it has no space in its buffer free and can't receive anymore data.

Comment: @syntonym But the connection is not being severed between process 1 and middle program. I need to achieve that

Comment: @AshishPatil Looks like TCP is keeping it alive? You wrote that you are trying to reproduce a bug in a different server, maybe you should try to look why TCP didn't keep it alive in that case?

Comment: @syntonym Yep, I'll ask him for a packet capture if he has it. If you have any other ideas to do this, please let me know. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @AshishPatil Maybe that problem is only reproducable if the ping is high? In that case you will probably to virtualize the network connection somehow but I think that a healthy TCP connection should not drop in that case.

Comment: @syntonym hmm yeah, thats very much possible. This makes it more interesting